# Describing hostnames / ports / URLs in English

Tags: url, port, hostname

This is the question I cannot figure out for quite some time. Which of the examples below are better to use?

```
a0. Open a "proto://127.0.0.2/?id=2" link
b0. Open "proto://127.0.0.2/?id=2" link
c0. Open a link "proto://127.0.0.2/?id=2
d0. Open the link "proto://127.0.0.2/?id=2"
e0. Open the "proto://127.0.0.2/?id=2" link
```

```
a1. In Windows 2003 / 208 only the 135 port accepts ...
b1. In Windows 2003 / 208 only 135 port accepts ...
```

```
a2. Service Provider was able to connect to MS Exchange using "EXCH1-TEST" hostname 
b2. Service Provider was able to connect to MS Exchange using hostname "EXCH1-TEST"
c2. Service Provider was able to connect to MS Exchange using the hostname "EXCH1-TEST"
d2. Service Provider was able to connect to MS Exchange using the "EXCH1-TEST" hostname
```

```
a3. available on port 135
b3. available on the 135 port
c3. available on 135 port
d3. available onto 135 port
e3. available onto the 135 port
```

Don't say this should be asked on English Language & Usage, for them it's off-topic.